# How i can correct install bit library in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip, centos6

I have a machine with Centos 6.10, python3.6, pip 21.3.1.

Link to bit library - https://pypi.org/project/bit/

All requirements are observed, other libraries I had installed without troubles

Try to install bit library `pip3.6 install bit` and get error.

Here is my error log.

```
 pip3.6 install bit==0.6.0
Collecting bit==0.6.0
  Downloading bit-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 64 kB 4.8 MB/s
Collecting coincurve>=4.3.0
  Using cached coincurve-16.0.0.tar.gz (219 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-package                                                                                                             s (from bit==0.6.0) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-pack                                                                                                             ages (from coincurve>=4.3.0->bit==0.6.0) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packa                                                                                                             ges (from coincurve>=4.3.0->bit==0.6.0) (1.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packag                                                                                                             es (from cffi>=1.3.0->coincurve>=4.3.0->bit==0.6.0) (2.21)
Building wheels for collected packages: coincurve
  Building wheel for coincurve (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/                                                                                                             _vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp8428zjtf
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-d7d9rq4f/coincurve_73e1ff44b1ce4f1697e0b1ab2cfdb003
  Complete output (66 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/types.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/context.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/_windows_libsecp256k1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coinc                                                                                                             urve
  copying coincurve/ecdsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/flags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/keys.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  copying coincurve/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/coincurve
  running build_clib
  configure.ac:407: error: AC_PROG_CC cannot be called after AM_PROG_CC_C_O
  build-aux/m4/ax_prog_cc_for_build.m4:38: AX_PROG_CC_FOR_BUILD is expanded from                                                                                                             ...
  configure.ac:407: the top level
  autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
  aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 1
  autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_                                                                                                             in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_                                                                                                             in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_                                                                                                             in_process.py", line 262, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-62lgckid/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setupt                                                                                                             ools/build_meta.py", line 231, in build_wheel
      wheel_directory, config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-62lgckid/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setupt                                                                                                             ools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-62lgckid/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setupt                                                                                                             ools/build_meta.py", line 268, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-62lgckid/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setupt                                                                                                             ools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 312, in <module>
      **setup_kwargs
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-62lgckid/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setupt                                                                                                             ools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 97, in run
      _bdist_wheel.run(self)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-62lgckid/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/                                                                                                             bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "setup.py", line 154, in run
      subprocess.check_call([autogen], cwd=absolute('libsecp256k1'))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-install-d7d9rq4f/coincurve_                                                                                                             73e1ff44b1ce4f1697e0b1ab2cfdb003/libsecp256k1/autogen.sh']' returned non-zero ex                                                                                                             it status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for coincurve
Failed to build coincurve
ERROR: Could not build wheels for coincurve, which is required to install pyproj                                                                                                             ect.toml-based projects
```

What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The important part of the error message is "error: AC_PROG_CC cannot be called after AM_PROG_CC_C_O" and maybe the next two lines. I suggest googling this to see if you can find a solution.